# LINQ: Select distinct from a lst and append different properties into one

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following problem, in which I would like to ask for help. I have to select distinct values(criteria by one property) and then extract the different values from the rest of the properties.

Let's say that I have the following class in which each `BOM` has one or more `FlatComponents` with different `Parts` and `QtyPer`.

Example:

```
public sealed class BOM {
    public string FlatComponent {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Part {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string QtyPer {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public BOM(String flatComponent, String part, String qtyPer) {
        this.FlatComponent=flatComponent;
        this.Part=part;
        this.QtyPer=qtyPer;
    }
}
```

```
List<BOM> list=new List<BOM>();
list.Add(new BOM("a", "1", "2"));
list.Add(new BOM("a", "3", "4"));
list.Add(new BOM("b", "5", "6"));
list.Add(new BOM("c", "7", "8"));
list.Add(new BOM("c", "9", "0"));
```

How would I select distinct `FlatComponents` and its diferent values in each property using LINQ(separated by comma)?

```
Result = [
    ["a", "1, 3", "2, 4"],
    ["b", "5", "6"],
    ["c", "7, 9", "8, 0"]
    ]
```

I have tried using `.Distinct()`, but I am pretty new with LINQ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = list
    .GroupBy(e => e.FlatComponent)
    .Select(e => new BOM
        {
            FlatComponent = e.Key,
            Part = string.Join(", ", e.Select(x => x.Part)),
            QtyPer = string.Join(", ", e.Select(x => x.QtyPer))
        });
```

It will create a distinct `BOM` for each `FlatComponent`, joining the `Part` and `QtyPer` properties with `", "`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a way to do it all in a single expression (and still have it be comprehensible), but here is some code that would do what you want:

[edit: didn't notice you had the part and qty as a single string, that changed it:]

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(item => item.FlatComponent);
List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (var group in groups) {
    var current = new List<string>();
    current.Add(group.Key);
    current.AddRange(group.Select(grp => string.Format("{0}, {1}", grp.Part, grp.QtyPer)));
    result.Add(current.Distinct().ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can often accomplish a distinct operation in LINQ using `GroupBy`.  This produces results in the format you gave for your desired results:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> asEnumerable = list.GroupBy(bom => bom.FlatComponent).Select(grouping => new string[] { grouping.Key, string.Join(", ", grouping.Select(bom => bom.Part)), string.Join(", ", grouping.Select(bom => bom.QtyPer)) });
string[][] asStringArray = asEnumerable.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// For convenience add read-only property
public sealed class BOM
{
    ...
    public string PartAndQuantity { get{return Part + ", " + QtyPer;} }
}

// Group by FlatComponent and then use string.Join:
var result = list.GroupBy (l => l.FlatComponent).Select(
    g => new 
    {
        Flat=g.Key, 
        Parts=string.Join(", ", g.Select (x => x.PartAndQuantity))
    });
```

Which will result in

```
Flat Parts 
a    "1, 2, 3, 4"
b    "5, 6"
c    "7, 8, 9, 0"
```

However you probably want

```
var result = list.GroupBy (l => l.FlatComponent).Select(
    g => new 
    {
        Flat=g.Key, 
        Parts=g.Select (x => x.PartAndQuantity).ToList()
    });
```